# Arrivederci auf Bayerisch

Tags: dialect, regional, salutation

In Niederbayern habe ich schon mehrmals einen Grußformeln zum Abschied gehört, was eigentlich wie die italienische 'arrivederci' klingt.

Auf [diesem Link](https://www.bayrisches-woerterbuch.de/bairisch-lernen/bairische-verabschiedung-abschied/) sieht man 'pfiat di' , 'wiederschaun', und 'servus' aber nichts was wie 'arrivederci' klingt, was ich ständig höre.

Gibt es so was oder habe ich falsch gehört?

Comment: Meine Vermutung ist, dass du das originale *arrivederci* gehört hast. Es ist zwar nicht ganz so populär wie *ciao* und hat keine eingedeutschte Schreibung, aber in der Oberpfalz ist mir das das auch begegnet. Eine auch nur entfernt ähnlich klingende bayerische Grußformel ist mir nicht bekannt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Möglicherweise handelt es sich um "*habe die Ehre*" in irgendeiner Dialektvariante, siehe https://regiowiki.at/wiki/Habediehre.

"*Habe die Ehre*" als Abschiedsgruß habe ich in Oberbayern an der Grenze zum Ostallgäu öfter gehört.

Natürlich hat "*Habediehre*" nur eine entfernte Ähnlichkeit mit "*arrivederci*". Die Ähnlichkeit betrifft insbesondere die Folge der Vokale. Offensichtlich ergab sich durch diese Ähnlichkeit *für den OP* die falsch gehörte Interpretation der ungewohnten Grußformel. Das ist natürlich nicht allgemeingültig.

Comment: Wie soll es dazu kommen können, dass ein Bayer (oder irgendein Deutscher) arrivederci und Habediehre nur ansatzweise ähnlich ausspricht?

Comment: Ja das musste es  gewesen sein. Es war ein sehr komisch ausgesprochene _arrivederci_ also musste es eigentlich _habe die Ehre_ gewesen sein.